# By using union of int and char array finding the int value,but how this value is coming ?can tell anyone?

Tags: c++, byte, unions

I have written c++ code for understanding union concept.In the code I have assigned some character to char array and print the int value ,but I don't understand the its logic behind.need help?
below code I have written.

```
#include <iostream>
union float_u {
    int f;
   char a[sizeof(int)];
} data1;

  using namespace std;

int main()
{


    cout << "Size of union :" << sizeof(data1)<<endl;

   data1.a[0] = '@';
   data1.a[1]= '@';


   cout << "value of f :" << data1.f << endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Output coming like this:

Size of union :4

value of f :16448

Comment: it is undefined. No logic (other than implementation details). Did you read any documentation? Try  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union. Or you are making use of a compiler extension, then you need to read your compilers manual.

Comment: ok, I will go through once link you have shared @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: You have undefined behavior according to the C++ standards, since you have modified one member of a union, and then accessed the other.    In terms of what is happening, that will be specific to your compiler.

Comment: @Peter But in the union memory is sharing so if I assign value to one member then other member will give us output as assigned value ? or any garbage value?

Comment: @RajendraAware  The point of "undefined" is that the C++ standard doesn't say.    One of the cute features of undefined behaviour is that you can't really reason about it (or draw conclusions about what is happening) using test cases like you are - since any different outcome that might occur (today, next week, if your code is build with a different compiler) is just as correct as whatever you observe now.

Comment: "the other member will give us" and thats already where its going wrong. `data1.f` does strictly speaking not access the member of the union. `data1.f` has no meaning in terms of standard C++. It is not defined what happens when you write `data1.f` in your code. What actually happens when you run the program is a different story. To understand that you best study the output of the comiler directly

Comment: As others said, it is undefined. On a lower level, you might notice that 16448 is 0x4040 and '@' is 0x40.

Comment: @KlausGütter I got one thing is that data1.a[0] ='@' so it will consider 1st byte and ASCII value of '@' is 64 so it will in terms of bytes is like 01000000, again I have assigned data1.a[1]='@' so its will considered as 2nd bytes and its values is 01000000.Now i have assigned values for 2 bytes remaining bytes are empty that maybe 0. so my final value of data1.f is converting binary to decimal of 2 bytes as [0100 0000] [0100 0000] so 2^14+2^7 = 16384+64= 16448

Comment: can anyone confirm above logic is correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot understand C++ by writing code and studying its output. Thats because there are just too many ways to write C++ code that compiles without error, but has undefined bahvior.

I am quoting from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union.

> It is undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written.

You are writing to `a`. `a` is the active member of the union. Reading from `f` is undefined. You could in principle get any output.

> Many compilers implement, as a non-standard language extension, the ability to read inactive members of a union.

As far as I know type punning via unions is allowed in C, so its not too difficult for compilers to also allow it in C++. Though, when you make use of a compiler extension you need to be aware that it isnt standard portable C++, and you need to read your compilers manual.